# What are the key differences between a partially ordered set and a filtered family(directed) set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Partial order means the set has a "sequencing" and a "binary relation" while a filtered family is a set that that has reflexive and transitive property of "less than or equal to sign" and that every pair of elements has an upper bound.What is the binary relation in P.O set? What does every pair of elements have an upper bound mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a Poset the binary relation is $\preceq$ , i.e., for some of the pairs of elements in the set say $(a,b)$ either $a\preceq b$ or $b\preceq a$. But this might not be true for all such pairs, hence the term $partial\  order$.

As for Filtered Set, note that every filtered set is a poset but the converse is not true. By saying that every pair of elements has a upper bound it means  given $a,b$ we can always find some $c$ such that $a\preceq c$ and $b\preceq c$, where $\preceq$ is the binary relation which you are imposing on the set and it may vary. For example consider $\mathbb{N}$, the set of natural numbers, and let $\preceq$ be the ordinary ordering on $\mathbb{N}$. Then clearly it satisfies reflexivity and transitivity. Now consider any pair of elements, say $2$ and $5$, $6\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $2\preceq 6$ and $5\preceq 6$.

Hope this helps.